# Python, Calibre, Open exe from URL Link

Tags: python, calibre

I would like to be able to open an .exe, from inside the Calibre program.
http://calibre-ebook.com/ (Opensource coded in python)

At present a details window will show a user defined URL, which will open in default browser, what I'm after is some way to incept that url, so I can open a exe file instead.

Or any way to open an exe file from within Calibre, ie from one of the entries, maybe batch file support or something

Don't know if this is possible, easy, or hard to do, but if someone could point me in the direction I need to look I would be very grateful.

(IT Pro, but no programming exp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Open with plugin](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118761) allows you to launch external applications.

Comment: Thanks Sebastion, but the pluging only allows "predefined default applications" like to choose what application to open a cover in, or what pdf reader to use. I want to open an unreleated application.

For example if I used calbre to catalogue games, I would use an empty txt file as the "record" in Calibre, and when clicking on it, I would want the game application to open in windows, (preferably closing calibre)

Comment: @Transmitthis: As I understand it `wow.game_record` could be opened/edited by any application you choose for `*.game_record` filetype.

Comment: OMG - Your right, I didn't know it supported that file type. Thanks J.F. Sebastian you solved it